# What are the best practices for Azure account setup with a B2C tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to find information on how to best set up an Azure account/directory when leveraging a B2C tenant as part of the process. This includes how to have instances for both Production and Development.

Right now I have a primary Directory with a subscription, storage resource, and B2C tenant. But there's a second Directory which was created IIRC as part of the B2C setup. There are no resources under that Directory and I'm confused as to what its purpose is.

1. Should I add additional resources that I need to the main Directory or under that B2C one?
2. What exactly does that B2C directory do other than sit there? I'm so confused by its presence.
3. Is there an easy way to clone everything and create a copy for Prod/Dev or is it all manual?

**Edit**: It should have been obvious but wasn't.. the reason for the additional B2C AD is that it acts a container for all your users. Makes sense once you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Should I add additional resources that I need to the main Directory or under that B2C one?

It depends on you, if you want the B2C tenant be able to access Azure resources, you can [link your B2C tenant to your Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant). If you just want to use Azure B2C to authenticate users, there is no need to link it to azure subscription.

> 2.What exactly does that B2C directory do other than sit there? I'm so confused by its presence.

The B2C AD is a feature of Azure B2C, just like Azure AD. If you want to use Azure AD as the provider to your b2c sign flow, you can use this one or some other Azure AD tenants.

> 3.Is there an easy way to clone everything and create a copy for Prod/Dev or is it all manual?

I think you need to clone them manually. Some Azure resources also have a feature of clone. If you have some resources which need to be deployed multiple times, you can use [ARM template deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused by the B2C directory which is created. Let's say I create a brand new Azure account, and under that default Directory I add a B2C tenant. During that process it creates another Directory for the B2C tenant. So it sounds like if I only want B2C to auth users then all additional Azure resources should be created under the Default Directory and leave the B2C Directory (that it needs for some reason) alone and empty. Is that correct?

Comment: @znelson Azure resources are related to azure subscription, not related to azure ad. If you associated your subscription to an active directory, then you can control the users or applications in that ad to access your azure resources. Please note that Azure resources are not under directory. Azure AD or Azure B2C are used to Microsoft’s cloud-based identity and access management service.

Comment: @znelson You can have a look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Comment: Thanks, I understand all that. Again, why does B2C Tenant need its own Directory and what am I supposed to do with it? Ignore it? Link it to a subscription? It makes no sense when there’s a default main AD and then another one because the B2C setup created it.

Comment: @znelson I see. When you create a B2C tenant, there will be an Azure AD created with the same domain(organization) as B2C tenant by default. You can ignore it if you just want to use b2c authentication.